# Detecting unused props passed in components in React

Tags: reactjs, refactoring

I currently refactoring some old code and I'm curious if there's any way to detect parameters which are passed into the component but never actually used inside it? Without looking at all the places where the component is called and checking manually.

Eg. detecting that **name** and **age** are not used inside the **Greet** component so can be deleted.

```
export default function Greet ({ greeting }) {
  return (
    <h1>{greeting}</h1>
  )
}

<Greet greeting="Hello Word" name="David" age="100"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript will warn you if you try to pass unknown props.

Eslint will warn you if you have unused variables, imports ...
with rules like:

- no-unused-expressions
- no-unused-vars
- react/no-unused-prop-types
- unused-imports